# In a .net 5 C# csproj, how can I set the Assembly Name for each target framework separately?

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-5

I created a simple C# Winforms project using TargetFrameworks.
for example:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
      <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net472|AnyCPU'">        
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net472|AnyCPU'">      
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-windows|AnyCPU'">        
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-windows|AnyCPU'">      
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net472'">
        <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

so i can build this project by targetframework. now I want to generate a different assembly name for each targetframework. this is the result:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFrameworks>net472;net6.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
      <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
      <Nullable>disable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net472|AnyCPU'">        
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
        <AssemblyName>WinFormsApp2_Net472_Debug</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net472|AnyCPU'">      
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
        <AssemblyName>WinFormsApp2_Net472_Release</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|net6.0-windows|AnyCPU'">        
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
        <AssemblyName>WinFormsApp2_Net6.0_Debug</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net6.0-windows|AnyCPU'">      
        <DefineConstants>$(DefineConstants)TRACE;;</DefineConstants>
        <AssemblyName>WinFormsApp2_Net6.0_Release</AssemblyName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='net472'">
        <Reference Include="System.Windows.Forms" />
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

when I compile this project, it output errors:

```
1>------ 已启动全部重新生成: 项目: WinFormsApp2, 配置: Debug Any CPU ------
未能还原 F:\Projects\WinFormsApp2\WinFormsApp2\WinFormsApp2.csproj (用时 0.6 ms)。
NuGet 包还原失败。请查看“错误列表”窗口了解详细警告和错误。
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: 资产文件“F:\Projects\WinFormsApp2\WinFormsApp2\obj\project.assets.json”没有“net472”的目标。确保已运行还原，且“net472”已包含在项目的 TargetFrameworks 中。
1>已完成生成项目“WinFormsApp2.csproj”的操作 - 失败。
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: 资产文件“F:\Projects\WinFormsApp2\WinFormsApp2\obj\project.assets.json”没有“net6.0-windows”的目标。确保已运行还原，且“net6.0-windows”已包含在项目的 TargetFrameworks 中。
1>已完成生成项目“WinFormsApp2.csproj”的操作 - 失败。
========== 全部重新生成: 成功 0 个，失败 1 个，跳过 0 个 ==========
```

If I remove all  in all PropertyGroups, it build success. I use Visual studio 2022.
Do you know what causes this? Is there any way to solve it?

---

english here:

```
1>------ Rebuild all started: Project: WinFormsApp2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
Failed to restore F:\Projects\WinFormsApp2\WinFormsApp2\WinFormsApp2.csproj (took 0.6 ms).
NuGet package restore failed. Please see the Error List window for detailed warnings and errors.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Asset file "F:\Projects\WinFormsApp2\ WinFormsApp2\obj\project.assets.json" has no target for "net472". Make sure a restore is run and "net472" is included in the project's TargetFrameworks.
1> Finished generating project "WinFormsApp2.csproj" - failed.
1>C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.101\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(267,5): error NETSDK1005: Asset file "F:\Projects\WinFormsApp2\ WinFormsApp2\obj\project.assets.json" has no target for "net6.0-windows". Make sure restore is run and "net6.0-windows" is included in the project's TargetFrameworks.
1> Finished generating project "WinFormsApp2.csproj" - failed.
========== Regenerate all: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: the error is : assets doesn't have a target for 'net472'...

Comment: Can you change the errors in the question to English? also, why do you want different assembly names for different versions?

Comment: hi, you can create a simple winform project with targetframework=.net 6.0, and change the csproj. you can reproduce this question. I want to generate different assembly for each target framework. for example, when I build with .net framework 4.7.2, it generate a WinFormsApp2.NetFramework.exe; if I build with .net 6.0, it generate WinFormsApp2.net60.exe.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this

```
  <!-- INCLUDE ASSEMBIES LINUX:-->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug_x64_Linux' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Release_x64_Linux'">
    <Reference Include="MyLinuxDll">
      <HintPath>.../MyLinuxDll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <!-- INCLUDE ASSEMBIES WINDOWS:-->
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug_x64_Windows' Or '$(Configuration)'=='Release_x64_Windows'">
    <Reference Include="MyWinDll">
      <HintPath>.../MyWindll.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

In this example I've create these 4 configurations in VS:

[image]